# How to split a string in x equal lines in javascript (with text justified)

Tags: javascript, string, lines, hyphenation

I am desperately trying to split a random string into equal parts, so I can theme each of them separately. My goal is making a twisted effect for my text, but keeping the text justifying and without splitted words..

As you can see on this example, I have tried to do something like that but the result is really crappy.:

http://vps10937.ovh.net/hyphenator/WorkingExample1.html (Platon 2)

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('p.platon2').each(function(index) {
    lengthTotal = jQuery(this).text().length
    var string = jQuery(this).text();
    string = jQuery.trim(string);
    var length = 56;
    var trimmedString = string.substring(0, length);
    jQuery(this).text('');
    lengthTotalPrev = 0;
    j=0;
    z=0
      for (i=length; i<lengthTotal;  i=i+length){
        j++;
        z=z+5;
        rowString = string.substring(lengthTotalPrev, i);
        jQuery(this).append('<span id="row'+j+'" class="rows" style="position:relative;left:-'+z+'px;">'+rowString+'</span>');
        lengthTotalPrev = i;
      }
    });
});
```

Now I'm trying to use the plugin [hyphenator.js](http://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/) to split correctly my text and get equal lines.

http://vps10937.ovh.net/hyphenator/WorkingExample1.html  ( Platon 1)

To call the plugin, it's very easy:

```
Hyphenator.config({
    displaytogglebox : true,
    minwordlength : 4
});
Hyphenator.run();
```

The result is pretty, but with this I can not apply CSS on each line to make my text twisted. I have explored the [hyphenator.js](http://vps10937.ovh.net/hyphenator/Hyphenator.js) (click here see source code) file from top to bottom, but haven't found anything to split the text on lines..

---

***EDIT***

---

I have modified [a plugin I found on github](https://gist.github.com/907237). With this, I am now able to do something close to the result wished. But there are still some problems.

http://vps10937.ovh.net/hyphenator/WorkingExample1.html (Platon 3)

1) **The script is very slow**. Is it possible to cache the result?

2) Text is no more justified, so lines are not exactly equals...

3) Only works on **Firefox!!**

[Here is the code http://vps10937.ovh.net/hyphenator/jquery.truncatelines.js](http://vps10937.ovh.net/hyphenator/jquery.truncatelines.js)

```
$.fn.truncateLines = function(options) {
options = $.extend($.fn.truncateLines.defaults, options);

return this.each(function(index, container) {

    container = $(container);
    var containerLineHeight = Math.ceil(parseFloat(container.css('line-height')));

    var maxHeightFixed = containerLineHeight;
    //var maxHeight = options.lines * containerLineHeight;

    var truncated = false;
    var truncatedText = $.trim(container.text());
    //var overflowRatio = container.height() / maxHeight;

    var oldTruncatedText; // verify that the text has been truncated, otherwise you'll get an endless loop
    var oldContainerHeight;
    textArray= new Array();

    jQuery(document.body).append('<p class="paragraphProvisory1" style="display: none;"></p>');
    jQuery(document.body).append('<p class="paragraphProvisory2" style="display: none;"></p>');

    while (container.height() > 0 && oldTruncatedText != truncatedText) {
        if(oldContainerHeight!=container.height()){


            truncatedTextTest = truncatedText;
            jQuery('.paragraphProvisory1').text(truncatedTextTest);

            //11nd line 
            if(container.height()==containerLineHeight*11){
                createLine(10);
            }
            //10nd line 
            if(container.height()==containerLineHeight*10){
                createLine(9);
            }
            //9nd line  
            if(container.height()==containerLineHeight*9){
                createLine(8);
            }
            //8nd line  
            if(container.height()==containerLineHeight*8){
                createLine(7);
            }
            //7nd line  
            if(container.height()==containerLineHeight*7){
                createLine(6);
            }
            //6nd line  
            if(container.height()==containerLineHeight*6){
                createLine(5);
            }
            //5nd line  
            if(container.height()==containerLineHeight*5){
                createLine(4);
            }
            //4nd line  
            if(container.height()==containerLineHeight*4){
                createLine(3);
            }
            //3nd line  
            if(container.height()==containerLineHeight*3){
                createLine(2);
            }
            //2nd line  
            if(container.height()==containerLineHeight*2){
                createLine(1);
            }
            //1st line      
            if(container.height()==containerLineHeight*1){
                textArray[0]= "<div class='line1'>"+truncatedTextTest+"</div>";     
            }

        }

        oldTruncatedText = truncatedText;
        oldContainerHeight = container.height()
        truncatedText = truncatedText.replace(/\s.[^\s]*\s?$/, ''); // remove last word
        container.text(truncatedText);

    }

    jQuery('.platon3').text('');
    jQuery.each(textArray, function(i) {
     jQuery('.platon3').append(textArray[i]);
});

});
};
function createLine(rowNumber){
    var oldTruncatedTextTest;
    var row = 0;
    positionLeft = rowNumber * 10;
    rowNumber++;
    jQuery('.paragraphProvisory2').text(truncatedTextTest);
        containerTest = $('.paragraphProvisory2');
        while (containerTest.height() > 20 && oldTruncatedTextTest != truncatedTextTest) {
            row++;
            oldTruncatedTextTest = truncatedTextTest;
            truncatedTextTest = truncatedTextTest.substr(truncatedTextTest.indexOf(" ") + 1);
            jQuery('.paragraphProvisory2').text(truncatedTextTest);
            if(containerTest.height()==20){
                textArray[rowNumber]= "<div class='line"+rowNumber+"' style='position: relative; left: -"+positionLeft+"px;'>"+truncatedTextTest+"</div>";
            }
        }
};
```

Comment: Why not post the code you have created thus far. So that others can help you build on that code.

Comment: As you wanted, I posted all I have!

Comment: That's super intriguing!  I'm assuming that you never did find a cross browser solution you're content with?  I was considering the possibility for dividing content into horizontal equal columns or even blocks to emulate the many media slider transitions out there. Moving to canvas would probably be easier (although I haven't used canvas enough to really know)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what you want, but you could skew the entire text container to suit using css3:

```
.platon {
  transform: skew(160deg,0deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(160deg,0deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(160deg,0deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(160deg,0deg);
  -o-transform: skew(160deg,0deg);
  width: 367px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, but I already know this css rule. The problem is the compatibility with internet explorer. I need it absolutely functional in every browser. http://vps10937.ovh.net/hyphenator/WorkingExample1.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to apply your own CSS to each *hyphenated* line...
So you would define your own `classname` like this:

```
        Hyphenator.config({                
classname : 'yourclass',             

 })
```

Comment: Hello no it's not exactly what I need. I want something like my example Platon 3 http://vps10937.ovh.net/hyphenator/WorkingExample1.html .But the lines aren't exactly equals